# ORA 03134 error connecting ODP.NET 12 (VS2012) to Oracle database 11

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

When trying to connect to Oracle 9.2 from VS2012 using ODP.NET 12, I have got this message:

ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported

I have installed ODP.NET 11 and I got the same error, although connecting with Toad is working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, uninstalling version 12 of ODP.NET, as version 12 is not supporting Oracle 9.2 databases.

ODP.NET version 11 works with version 9.2 and above.