# PowerShell Error "ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported" when trying to open connection

Tags: .net, database, oracle, powershell, plsql

I am trying to query an Oracle database through PowerShell. The version of the oracle database is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.7.0 - Production.

Whe I run the following

```
### open up oracle connection to database ###
$OracleConnection = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($OracleConnectionString);
$OracleConnection.Open()
```

I am receiving the following error

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ORA-03134: Connections
>   to this server version are no longer supported.

Is this something to do with the connection string? Please advise

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA 03134 error connecting ODP.NET 12 (VS2012) to Oracle database 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688485/ora-03134-error-connecting-odp-net-12-vs2012-to-oracle-database-11)

Comment: Oracle 9.2 was released in the year 2002.  May be time to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

The .Net Oracle provider doesn't support Oracle 9 anymore, so the connection won't work at all. In addition, MS is [about to deprecate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient(v=vs.110).aspx) Oracle support. As per the documentation:

> This types in System.Data.OracleClient are deprecated and will be
>   removed in a future version of the .NET Framework.

Consider using Oracle's [own data provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/multipledbs-089665.html) instead.